# How to set break points in python class's member function by pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

For example:

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        pass
```

how to set bp in func while using python pdb to debug? I have try `b A::func`, `b func`, `b A.func`, nether is works...

Thank you~

Answer (score 2):

## Setting a breakpoint

You can do the folowing and just run your code normally:

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        pass
```

Having the import and the set_trace() command on the same line allows for easy cleanup.

## Navigating

A debugging prompt should appear when you run your program. Use the pdb shortcuts to step the debugger:

- s(tep) : Execute the current line, stop at the first possible occasion (either in a function that is called or on the next line in the current function).
- n(ext) : Continue execution until the next line in the current function is reached or it returns. (The difference between next and step is that step stops inside a called function, while next executes called functions at (nearly) full speed, only stopping at the next line in the current function.)
- unt(il) : Continue execution until the line with the line number greater than the current one is reached or when returning from current frame.
- r(eturn) : Continue execution until the current function returns.
- c(ont(inue)) : Continue execution, only stop when a breakpoint is encountered.

See the docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pdb

class A:
 def func(self):
    pdb.set_trace()
    pass
```